# What is the center most point of a set of points?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Given a set of points in the plane $\\{p_1, p_2, \cdot \cdot \cdot, p_n\\}$ from which I don't know their position but the distances from each other. How can I determine the point that lies closest to the center point of this set of points?

Comment: under center point you mean barycenter. (center of mass?)

Comment: I mean the centroid or the mean position of all the points.